# Pentaho - Launching a job parallel to the Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I created job in Pentaho as below:
[image]

Job working in spoon, but when I want to run this job from Task Scheduler as .bat file, it doesn't work. I don't know why. The job status is running every time, but it goes on indefinitely.

My .bat file
I have a problem only with parallel

[image]

Comment: can you provide more details.

Comment: I have one job where transformations are run in parallel. I have about 20 transformation.
From pentaho-data-integration, this job takes less than an hour.
I wanted to run this job from the Task Scheduler, where I specified all the required parameters. As I set the schedule in task scheduler, the job starts but nothing happens. It looks like it's hung up.